# stuck because of 'old' inlog name of apple id

Tags: ipad, icloud, email, apple-id, login

I used to have an ipad2, it 'died' about 12 months ago. 
Last week I bought a new ipad Air2.
Meanwhile in past 12 months the login name of my Apple id was changed.

1. Since changing the e-mail address of the Apple id I have had problems constantly, because the old inlog name keeps popping up. But I thought I had solved hat problem.
2. Yesterday I 'uploaded' the 'old' ipad profile from October 2014, because of the apps I bought in the past few years, but with that also the old login name came with the ipad profile. 
   Now I cannot do anything with the brand new iPad, because the old Apple id Login name doesn't accept any of my old passwords.....And after going to the motion of 'adapting' the apple id on the ipad, I can still not login into the ipad, because the old apple id login name does not change.

3.a. Then I thought, let's forget about the old ipad back up, and overwrite it back to factory settings...
3.a.1 For that I need a "limitations'-code, that I do not have.
3.b. Then I thought, let's forget about the old ipad back up, and reset it through itunes...
3.b.2 I need the password fitting my 'old' inlogname of my apple id.. i tried several, but they are not accepted.

So, I do not know what to do....

Comment: start at https://iforgot.apple.com

Comment: I finally got through to Apple Care in The Netherlands. They helped me with following..... On a computer on internet at id.apple.com I deleted my 'old' e-mail address from the list of alternate e-mail addresses in my Apple id Account. Then changed the current primary log name from my Apple id into the 'old' one. After that I was able to log into iCloud on the iPad, turn of "Find my iPad', and log out of iCloud on iPad. And after that I went to iTunes and 'reset' iPad..... Now I can start all over again with setting the iPad up, but I think this is the only way.

Comment: Awesome comment Nicole. If you would add it to the answer section, we could help out others know you found a solution by checking the "answered" box and having a proper answer.